# May have not or may not have?

Tags: word-order

Which sentence is correct?

This can lead us to learn about other strengths we have, we may otherwise **have not/not have** discovered.

This can lead us to discover about other strengths we have, we may otherwise **have not/not have.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither sentence is correct.

The first sentence would be correct if it read:

> This can lead us to learn about other strengths we have *that* we may otherwise *not have discovered*.

That's to say the natural word order is: **may not have discovered.** It might be possible to construct valid sentences using **may have not discovered** but these would be the exception.

The second sentence is not logical.

Either you have the strengths that you mention or you do not have them. It is possible only to discover strengths that you have. Nothing can lead you to discover strengths that you do not have. You can only discover strengths that you did not know you have.

Note that **discover**, unlike learn, does not take the preposition *about*. One discovers things; one does not discover about them - although one may discover *something* about them.